When will the measure of the boundary of a domain have a upper bound w.r.t the diameter
Let $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain. When will the following upper bound hold?
$$
\mathscr{H}^{n-1} (\partial \Omega) \leq C
(\text{diam} (\Omega))^{n-1}.  
$$
Here $\partial \Omega$ is the boundary of $\Omega$, $\mathscr{H}^{n-1}$ is the $n-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure, $\text{diam}(\Omega)$ is the diameter of $\Omega$, and $C$ is a positive constant independent of $\Omega$. This is true for the ball (or even for a convex set; see here). So, what is the weakest condition that make this upper bound hold, or are there any other conditions that could make this upper bound valid.
I guass we need some smooth condition on the domain $\Omega$. However, geometric measure theory is totally unknow for me. Any hints or reference will be helpful.

@Balajisb, I think isoperimetric inequality gives a lower bound, not an upper bound.
